# Injecting script in DOM

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.body.innerHTML = "An error occurred. Please try to login again.<br>";

document.body.innerHTML += 'Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>';
document.body.innerHTML += 'Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>';
document.body.innerHTML += "<input type='submit' value='Login' onclick='alert(document.getElementById('password').value)'>"
```

After running this code and then clicking the login button the Chrome JavaScript console gives back:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the quotes and escape them inside the javascript code:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "An error occurred. Please try to login again.<br>";

document.body.innerHTML += 'Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>';
document.body.innerHTML += 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>';
document.body.innerHTML += "<input type='submit' value='Login' onclick='alert(document.getElementById(\"password\").value)'>";
```

> As for the reason "why the browser throws this specific error?", here is the question:

Because the code is wrong, the browser actually see the following code:

```
(function(event){alert(document.getElementById(
})
```

As you can see - after the `document.getElementById(` there is a closing `{`, which is what your browser is yelling at you about.

Comment: Click on the login button.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek actually there was an error :) and I updated the answer

Comment: @WayneXMayersX check the answer now

Comment: why it throws that error when quotes are not escaped? =/

Comment: OP also is trying to access a `id` which doesn't exist, you may want to include that as well.

Comment: The error is not because the quotes are not escaped, it's because the you used wrong quotes.

Comment: @Dekel but why it says "Unexpected token }" when there is not "}" at all? I'm confused =/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek added the id to the password input

Comment: @Dekel Works for me, not sure why the person that copied you answer got an up vote rather than the first one. +1

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks for the vote. Regarding the other answer - I'm not sure, but it happen :)

Answer (score 1):

Just escape quotes

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "An error occurred. Please try to login again.<br>";

document.body.innerHTML += 'Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>';
document.body.innerHTML += 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>';
document.body.innerHTML += "<input type='submit' value='Login'  onclick='alert(document.getElementById(\"password\").value);return false;' />"
```